# HWIOAuthBundle How get user data in controloler?

Tags: oauth, symfony

In this doc exist $response variable
https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/internals/response_object_and_paths.md

but i I do not understand, how $response came to the controller.

Help, please! Give me example, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement own custom User Provider which is gonna use HWIOAuthBundle for loading user's data (analogically as if you want to load users from own SQL table, for example).

Here is good example: https://gist.github.com/danvbe/4476697

And the Symfony's doc [How to Create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html)

**EDIT**

The controller doesn't have access to HWIOAuthBundle's UserResponseInterface, your UserProvider does, so if you want to access realName of the user in the controller, you have to do it through user entity.

User provider:

```
...
public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response)
{
    $userEmail = $response->getEmail();
    $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($userEmail);

    // if null just create new user and set it properties
    if (null === $user) {
        $realName = $response->getRealName();
        $user = new User();
        $user->setRealName($realName);
...
```

Controller:

```
...
public function defaultAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->getUser()->getRealName();
...
```

Comment: thank you. i use this example, but i I do not understand, how i can use getRealName(); in defaultController. 

what files should I connect?

I will be very grateful for the example of using the methods of the bundle to the controller

Comment: thanks @honza-rydrych

but, there is a request to the api, even if we do not call the method getRealName()?

for example we call $this->getUser()->getEmail() (from database)
and at the same time there is a request to the api of the social network

this solution is not very efficient :(

Comment: I think we are talking about different things. One thing is, when you need to authenticate a user, you have to retrieve data from where they are (sqlDB or social network API) and provide this data to Symfony's security - it has to be done by User provider and that's what I described above. Another thing is when you want to play with the oAuth directly in the controller's action, then there's a good example right in the HWIOAB repo:  https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/master/Controller/ConnectController.php